# How to update a field in a CSV file/table based on where it is on the map

Tags: fields-attributes, update

I have a shapefile which I downloaded that displays different region types. I also have a CSV file of geocoded addresses. I have loaded both into QGIS and can see the addresses scattered about on the map in different regions. I want to update my address file with the region code based on where it shows.
I had done something like this years ago in mapinfo using a query and object contains syntax, but not sure how to do this in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want to do a so-called **"spatial join"**.

See e.g. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html

Comment: Hi Mesa - thanks for the reply & the link. that was what I was looking for and I certainly would not have worked out that menu choice otherwise. Cheers